# How to get Instagram cookie with username and password?

Tags: node.js, cookies, request, instagram

I'm building an app that lets you connect with your username and password of your Instagram account and do some things in your account (for self use).

I'm trying to get my Instagram's cookie, but I don't know how.

I can see it in my browser's devTools requests but I have no idea how to get it in node, when I don't have Instagram to do it for me.

Is there any URL that I can send it the username & password of my account and get my account's cookie?

Comment: Why not just use the instagram APIs?

Comment: @x43 because I want to do things that those APIs doesn't provide for me - like get a list of all followers and followings